# What is the rank of a single-row matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Does it make sense to say that the rank of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 
\end{pmatrix}$ is $1?$ I see it forms a single independent vector. Or another way, we can write any column of the matrix as a linear combination of the other two. For example, $a_1 = \alpha a_2 + \beta a_3$, for some real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Nevertheless, when I try to calculate the rank of a $1\times3$ matrix online, no website (including WolframAlpha) seems to make sense of it. Why?

Comment: It has rank $0$ if all $a_i=0$ and rank $1$ otherwise. [Wolfram|Alpha example.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixRank%5B%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%7D%5D)

Comment: It forms a single independent vector unless $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$ in which case the rank is $0$. Also, WolframAlpha has no problem calculating the rank, [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rank+%7B%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%7D%7D) this example.